# import csv file in NEO4J

Tags: csv, neo4j

I'm on windows 7 and I'm new to Neo4J, I'm using Neo4J version 3.0.3.
I have a simple and small csv file, just for trying out how to import a csv file into Neo4j.

Here is my file, called people.csv

```
1,"John"
10,"Jane"
234,"Fred"
4893,"Mark"
234943,"Anne"
```

From neo4j browser's console I've tried in different ways to import this file but got no luck.
These are my attempts:

```
    USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:\Utenti\Luca\Desktop\people.csv"

which returned this error: Invalid input 't': expected four hexadecimal digits specifying a unicode character (line 1, column 56 (offset: 55))
"USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:\Utenti\Luca\Desktop\people.csv""
```

Then I tried with slashes.

```
    USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Utenti/Luca/Desktop/people.csv"

and the error was:
Unexpected end of input: expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or AS (line 1, column 86 (offset: 85))
"USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Utenti/Luca/Desktop/people.csv""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path in your second query looks correct. But you `LOAD` the csv file without doing anything.

The error tells you that it expects *something* after the first line (column 86 is the end of line).

Try e.g. to return the first few lines:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Utenti/Luca/Desktop/people.csv" AS line
WITH line
RETURN line
LIMIT 5
```

If you want to create something, read the manual: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-load-csv